# Is lowerAngleLimit on SKPhysicsJointPin broken?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsjoint

I have never gotten the upper/lower angle limits to work properly on SKPhysicsJointPin objects, and I think I've finally figured out why:  if the lowerAngleLimit is set to a negative value, it breaks every time.  It only works correctly with positive values.

For example, say I set this 90º pin:

```
    pin.lowerAngleLimit = -PI/2;
    pin.upperAngleLimit = 0;
```

Now I'll make the sprite rotate slowly towards that lower limit.  The instant it hits -90º it will suddenly *zoom* the sprite the long way around back to 0º.  It will never pin at -90º.  It doesn't matter what negative value I try, -1.0 does the exact same thing.  It appears to be a bug in SpriteKit.  Has anyone else gotten this to work, or found an workaround?

Comment: Did you every figure this out?  I am seeing similar and figure its a misunderstanding on what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: No, I never did.  It simply doesn't work correctly as is the case with much of Apple's gaming API's on iOS.